# Symfony aborts with Signal 5 "libssl.1.0.0 ERR Reason: image not found" on Bitmani MAPP

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I have run into an issue with Signal `5` in Symfony. I'm on a Mac 10.11.3 with Bitmani MAPP 5.6 installed. My IDE is PhpStorm, but I haven't used it for the demo project.

Here is my terminal readout:

> **Scotts-MacBook-Pro:PhpstormProjects syacko$** symfony demo
>
> Downloading the Symfony Demo Application...
>
> 6.68 MB/6.68 MB ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  100%
>   Preparing project...
>
> ✔  Symfony Demo Application was successfully installed. Now you can:
>
> 1. Change your current directory to /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo
> 2. Execute the php app/console server:run command to run the demo application.
> 3. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL to see the demo application in action.
>
> **Scotts-MacBook-Pro:PhpstormProjects syacko$** cd symfony_demo/
>
> **Scotts-MacBook-Pro:symfony_demo syacko$** php app/console server:run
>
> Server running on //127.0.0.1:8000
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
>
> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>      The process has been signaled with signal "5".
>
> server:run [-d|--docroot DOCROOT] [-r|--router ROUTER] [--] []

When I run with `-vvv`, the message saws that

> dyld: Library not loaded: /bitnami/mampstack-osx-x64/output/common/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

is missing. It is on the system at

> /Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/common/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

I tried creating a hard and symbolic link, but neither worked. Here is the complete read out.

> Scotts-MacBook-Pro:symfony_demo syacko$ php app/console server:run -vvv
>   [2016-02-24 18:53:13] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   [2016-02-24 18:53:13] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand".
>   [2016-02-24 18:53:13] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":55,"level":28928} 
>   Server running on //127.0.0.1:8000
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
>     RUN  '/Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/php/bin/php.bin' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8000' '/Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'
>     ERR  dyld: Library not loaded: /bitnami/mampstack-osx-x64/output/common/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>     ERR    Referenced from: /Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/php/bin/php.bin
>     ERR    Reason: image not found
>     ERR
>
> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>     The process has been signaled with signal "5".
>
> Exception trace:
>    () at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:361
>    Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:204
>    Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProcessHelper.php:63
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProcessHelper->run() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerRunCommand.php:134
>    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ServerRunCommand->execute() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:256
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:846
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:189
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
>    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:120
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/syacko/PhpstormProjects/symfony_demo/app/console:27
>
> server:run [-d|--docroot DOCROOT] [-r|--router ROUTER] [--] []

Comment: Can you please start the server with [`-vv` or maybe even `-vvv`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#verbosity-levels). You should get a complete exception trace output then; please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35615772/edit) it to your question.

Comment: @VolkerK Any ideas about how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Not really. I suggest that you post this message and maybe also the output of  `otool -L /Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/php/bin/php.bin` to the bitnami bug tracker.

Comment: Just one wild guess: If there is a libssl in /Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/common/lib/ you _might try `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/mappstack-5.6.18-1/common/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting the server. (At least it will not break anything on your system permanently, so it's probably safe to fiddle with ;-))

Comment: Thank you and I will try these items.

Comment: But please keep in mind that a) my knowledge of osx is virtually limited to "there is something called osx" ;-) so I chose two things that won't alter anything permanently on your system and b) you already did at least one thing that has permanent consequences if not undone: "I tried creating a hard and symbolic link, but neither worked. Here is the complete read out." Are you confident you've rolled those changes back to "vanilla"?

Comment: Hello - this has been confirmed as a bug in the Bitnami MAPP 5.5 and 5.6 release. It will be fixed in the next release by Bitnami.